# Resuse SSH Connection on Remote Machine

Tags: ssh

There are 3 UNIX boxes:

- Client
- Bounce Box
- Remote

The REMOTE machine only allows SSH connections from the bounce box.  On the BOUNCE box I have the following in the local SSH config file:

```
Host REMOTE
  HostName remote.domains.tld
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-r@%h
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist 4h
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The above allows me to reuse a single connection so I do not have to log in each time I need another console, etc...

Without using SSH tunneling (ie. `ssh -L 22:REMOTE:22 user@BOUNCE`), I would like to be able to connect from CLIENT to REMOTE and re-use the already open connection on BOUNCE so that I do not need to re-authenticate each time I want to open a new console.

It such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve what you're trying to do by also using a re-usable connection between CLIENT and BOUNCE, along with the `ProxyCommand` directive.

In the `~/.ssh/config` file on CLIENT:

```
Host REMOTE
  HostName remote.domains.tld
  ProxyCommand ssh BOUNCE -W %h:%p
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist 4h
```

Comment: When I tried this it prompted me to authenticate, which means it didn't reuse the already open connection on BOUNCE.